# Image Sequence to Movie - How to Get Desired Frame Rate (QT)?

Tags: animation

I rendered 250 png images for an animation.
In QuickTime (10.5), I open these images as an Image Sequence and set the frame rate to 24 per second. This should give me a movie of around 10 seconds.

I get a 10 second movie, **BUT** all 250 images play within the first 4 seconds, and the remaining 6 seconds are just a still frame of my 250th image!

When I enter other frame rates, like 60 / second, I get a 4 second movie, but all the movement is in the first 40%, then only a still frame.

***How can I create a movie from my 250 png images that actually plays at 24 or 25 fps?***

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Video editing questions are [off-topic here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Sorry about that. Maybe try Video Production Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: @BillyKerr reposted at Blender SE. Can you close it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, I would recommend that you use VirtualDub2 http://virtualdub2.com/. It is a very simple program.

1. File > Open - your first frame, and if they are consecutive numbers it will be loaded as one clip.
2. Video > Compression - And select the codec you want. If you want to export to Mp4 use x286 8 bit
3. Video > Frame Rate > Change Frame Rate to - If you want exactly 10 seconds, use 25 FPS
4. File > Save as - And choose your output file.

(You probably need to: Audio > No Audio)

You can even export to animated GIF. You do not have control over the generated palette or dither, but if your animation is flat enough it will compress well.

Comment: QuickTime (10.5) says Mac through & through. QuickTime for Windows was discontinued in 2016.

Comment: Yeap, I would not use QT for this.

Comment: @Rafael, thank you for your suggestion. I am Mac through and through though...